# Store a managed reference in unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to store a reference to a regular managed object (not pinned) in an unmanaged memory area? Essentially, rather than pinning the object, I'd like to mark the area as a GC root or something like that. I've looked at the GCHandle documentation but it's rather unclear as to whether it actually can do this.

Comment: As far as I know *all* non-pinned objects can be moved and corresponding managed references will be patched... Even if you an find something internal I'd not rely on such behavior...

Comment: GCHandle required so the object can't be collected.  Its ToIntPtr() method provides a way to generate a value you can store in unmanaged memory.  Convert back with FromIntPtr() and Target.  You'd use the gcroot<> class in C++/CLI to do all of this automatically.

Comment: @HansPassant: Right, but I don't see how GCHandle can possibly provide such a function when you could be storing that pointer value in any random place through that interface. So how could the pointers be updated when the object is moved? Or are we really talking about some sort of handle/other indirection?

Comment: The IntPtr generated by ToIntPtr() provides a reference to the handle, not the object.  The handles don't move, only the object does.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes a bit more sense. And then Free() presumably frees this spare handle?

Comment: Similar question with more detailed answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295586/save-reference-to-managed-object-in-unmanaged-memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GCHandle can do this. The only downside is that it is untyped, but that's not a big issue as it's simple enough to create a typed wrapper around GCHandle.