# Save reference to managed object in unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I want to put a reference to a C# object into unmanaged memory (C), I guess as a pointer (int), and when the C code calls back into C# later on, I want to get the reference back from the unmanaged memory, so I can resolve it, and access the object. The reason is that the C code controls which object should be used, there's no real alternative. I have limited control over the C code and C++/CLI is not an option.

Question: Is that possible and safe, if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it is possible.  Primary concern is that your scheme is very incompatible with the garbage collector, it moves objects in memory when it compacts the heap.  That's something you can stop, you can *pin* the object so the GC cannot move it.  You use GCHandle.Alloc() to allocate a GCHandleType.Pinned handle and pass the return value of GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject() to your C code, presumably with a pinvoke call.

You have to fret about how long that object needs to stay pinned.  A couple of seconds, tops, is okay, but it gets pretty detrimental to the GC if you keep it pinned for a long time.  It is a rock in the road that the GC constantly has to drive around.  And the heap segment can never be recycled, that single object can cost you a handful of megabytes.

In which case you should consider allocating unmanaged memory and copying the object into it.  Use Marshal.AllocHGlobal() to allocate, Marshal.StructureToPtr() to copy the object into it.  Possibly multiple times if you modify the object and the changes need to be visible to the C code as well.

Either way, the object must be *blittable* or you get a runtime error.  An expensive word that just means that the object must have simple field types, the kind that a C program has a shot at reading correctly.  Don't use *bool*.  Be careful with the declaration in the C program, pretty easy to corrupt the heap when you get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer, as it's the thing closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

When you control the 'handing out' and the 'use after receiving back' phases you can simply use a List or array and pass around the index.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. The reason for this question was that potentially a lot of calls will come from the unmanaged side, and I wagered that casting a pointer to an object would probably be faster than looking up a value in a Dictionary. For some reason I didn't think of using a list or array. I might do it like this, thanks xD"

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to consume C# objects via COM and proxies created by the CLR called [COM-Callable Wrappers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c(v=VS.110).aspx).

You just need assign a GUID assembly attribute to identify the COM type library, e.g.:

```
[assembly: Guid ("39ec755f-022e-497a-9ac8-70ba92cfdb7c")]
```

And then use the [Type Library Exporter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c(v=vs.110).aspx) tool (*tlbexp.exe*) to genereate the COM type library (.tlb) file which can be consumed in the COM world:

```
tlbexp.exe YourLibrary.dll
```

If you mean safe in the C#'s sense of the word, then certainly unsafe, as you'll be using the objects in the unmanaged world, and lifetimes are controlled from the COM side via reference counting as opposed to CLR's GC.